# How to implement Interceptors in Quarkus for specific scenarios

Tags: java, rest, quarkus, interceptor, quarkus-reactive

I am new in Quarkus and I need to create two filters

1. The first one must be executed for each specific method that I have defined in a controller, I have seen that there are some implementations in Quarkus but they are executed globally for all the defined endpoints, is there any way to specify to the same method which filter to use ??

Or what would be the best way to implement it, I would appreciate your suggestions on how to do it in a real environment using Quarkus.

2. The second filter is one that must be executed when there is an exception of any type in any layer, be it Controller, Service, Repository, etc, the idea is to capture that exception with the message to later return it in the response, is there any way to do it in Quarkus?

I would appreciate if someone could give me more light, or related documentation since I am just starting with Quarkus and I can not solve it.

Comment: Since Quarkus is built on top of CDI & Jax-RS, for the first one, you may have a look about CDI interceptors first then take a look at this:
https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference

Regarding the second point you may use Jax-RS exception mappers:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=applications-defining-exception-mappers-resource-exceptions-errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.